# How to ignore namespaces with JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, pojo

I am working with a legacy application and I need to unmarshall the following payload

```
<InventoryItem><Vehicle xis:type="ns2:car"/></InventoryItem>
```

I have a InventoryItem, Vehicle, Car and Truck classes. And in my Vehicle class, I defined the following JsonTypeInfo

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes ({
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Truck.class, name = "ns2:truck"), 
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Car.class, name = "ns2:car")
})
public class Vehicle
```

It works as expected. But how do hint to ignore namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

I had to introduce a resolver to solve it...

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonTypeIdResolver(VehicleTypeResolver.class)
public class Vehicle

public class VehicleTypeResolver extends TypeIdResolverBase {
    private JavaType superType;

    @Override
    public void init(JavaType baseType) {
        superType = baseType;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonTypeInfo.Id getMechanism() {
        return JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValue(Object obj) {
        return idFromValueAndType(obj, obj.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValueAndType(Object obj, Class<?> subType) {
        String typeId = null;
        String[] split = ((Vehicle)obj).getType().split(":");
        typeId = split[0] + ':' + subType.getSimpleName();
        return typeId;
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext context, String id) {
        Class<?> subType = null;
        String[] split = id.split(":");
        switch (split[1]) {
            case "car":
                subType = Car.class;
                break;
            case "truck":
                subType = Truck.class;
        }
        return context.constructSpecializedType(superType, subType);
    }
}
```

and here is my sample schema which I generated using jsonchema2pojo and customized the pojos on top of it. I tried 'deserializationClassProperty' offered by jsonschema2pojo and had no luck.

```
vehicle.json
{
  "type": "object",
  "id": "#Vehicle",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "javaType": "Vehicle",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "color": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
car.json
{
  "type": "object",
  "id": "#Car",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "javaType": "Car",
  "extends": {
    "type": "object",
    "existingJavaType": "Vehicle"
  }
}
truck.json
{
  "type": "object",
  "id": "#Truck",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "javaType": "Truck",
  "extends": {
    "type": "object",
    "existingJavaType": "Vehicle"
  }
}
```

quick note: the 'type' property on the vehicle is the trick, it was unmarshalling fine but to get marshalling to work, I had to add the following annotation to get it to work

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "type", isAttribute = true, namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;
```